# how can we call a subroutine in main program and taking its output in main program?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, fortran77

I want to call a subroutine in the main program and also want to get the output of that subroutine in the main program but when I write the output in the subroutine its different than when I write it in the main program someone can tell me where I am wrong? while writing yy in subroutine and in main program gives different values.

```
  subroutine zlamda(lamdaroot)

  INTEGER N,NBMAX
  REAL X1,X2
  PARAMETER(N=100,NBMAX=20,X1=0.0,X2=3.141592/2.)      
  INTEGER i,nb
  REAL zbrent,root,tol,xb1(NBMAX),xb2(NBMAX)
  EXTERNAL zbrak,bess
  REAL bess,lamdaroot,lamda
  COMMON /flamda/ eL,z
  nb=NBMAX
  call zbrak(bess,X1,X2,N,xb1,xb2,nb)
  do 200 i=1,nb
    tol=(1.0e-6)*(xb1(i)+xb2(i))/2.0
    lamdaroot=zbrent(bess,xb1(i),xb2(i),tol)                     
    yy=lamdaroot
    
  write(*,*)yy,'=lamdaroot=yy'


  200  continue
  return
  END


   FUNCTION bess(lamda)  
  REAL bss,lamda,zz,x

  
  bess=0.5*sin(lamda)*sqrt(1.+3.*sin(lamda)**2)+(0.5/sqrt(3.))
 +    *log(abs(sqrt(3.)*sin(lamda)+sqrt(1.+3.*sin(lamda)**2)))
 +    -abs(zz)/4685.0     
   return  
   END 

SUBROUTINE zbrak(fx,x1,x2,n,xb1,xb2,nb)  
  INTEGER n,nb  
  REAL x1,x2,xb1(nb),xb2(nb),fx  
  EXTERNAL fx  
  INTEGER i,nbb  
  REAL dx,fc,fp,x  
  nbb=0  
  x=x1  
  dx=(x2-x1)/n  
  fp=fx(x)  
  do 11 i=1,n  
    x=x+dx  
    fc=fx(x)  
    if(fc*fp.le.0.) then  
      nbb=nbb+1  
      xb1(nbb)=x-dx  
      xb2(nbb)=x  
      if(nbb.eq.nb)goto 1  
    endif  
    fp=fc  
  11    continue  
  1     continue  
  nb=nbb  
  return   
  END  





  
   FUNCTION zbrent(func,x1,x2,tol)  
  INTEGER ITMAX  
  REAL zbrent,tol,x1,x2,func,EPS  
  EXTERNAL func  
  PARAMETER (ITMAX=100,EPS=3.e-8)  
  INTEGER iter  
  REAL a,b,c,d,e,fa,fb,fc,p,q,r,s,tol1,xm  
  a=x1  
  b=x2  
  fa=func(a)  
  fb=func(b)  
  if((fa.gt.0..and.fb.gt.0.).or.(fa.lt.0..and.fb.lt.0.))pause  
 *'root must be bracketed for zbrent'  
  c=b  
  fc=fb  
  do 11 iter=1,ITMAX  
    if((fb.gt.0..and.fc.gt.0.).or.(fb.lt.0..and.fc.lt.0.))then  
      c=a  
      fc=fa  
      d=b-a  
      e=d  
    endif  
    if(abs(fc).lt.abs(fb)) then  
      a=b  
      b=c  
      c=a  
      fa=fb  
      fb=fc  
      fc=fa  
    endif  
    tol1=2.*EPS*abs(b)+0.5*tol  
    xm=.5*(c-b)  
    if(abs(xm).le.tol1 .or. fb.eq.0.)then  
      zbrent=b  
      return  
    endif  
    if(abs(e).ge.tol1 .and. abs(fa).gt.abs(fb)) then  
      s=fb/fa  
      if(a.eq.c) then  
        p=2.*xm*s  
        q=1.-s  
      else  
        q=fa/fc  
        r=fb/fc  
        p=s*(2.*xm*q*(q-r)-(b-a)*(r-1.))  
        q=(q-1.)*(r-1.)*(s-1.)  
      endif  
      if(p.gt.0.) q=-q  
      p=abs(p)  
      if(2.*p .lt. min(3.*xm*q-abs(tol1*q),abs(e*q))) then  
        e=d  
        d=p/q  
      else  
        d=xm  
        e=d  
      endif  
    else  
      d=xm  
      e=d  
    endif  
    a=b  
    fa=fb  
    if(abs(d) .gt. tol1) then  
      b=b+d  
    else  
      b=b+sign(tol1,xm)  
    endif  
    fb=func(b)  
  11    continue  
  pause 'zbrent exceeding maximum iterations'  
  zbrent=b  
  return  
  END
```

and main program is

```
 program main
  implicit none
  
  real yy,lamdaroot
  
  call zlamda(lamdaroot)
  
  write(*,*)yy
  
  stop
  endprogram main
```

Comment: Please get any reference book on Fortran programming.  You never set the value of `yy` in `program main`.  Your code is invalid.  PS: You should add `implicit none` to all of your program units and declare all variables.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. How different are the results, how does the other code look like? See also [ask]. Be aware that Fortran 77 is hopelessly obsolete and you cannot do many useful things that help with error detection in modern Fortran (modules!). You **must** use at least `IMPLICIT NONE` in each unit. It is completely necessary.

Comment: alright, thank you for your suggestions I will do that